# Strange pointers initialization

Tags: c, pointers

Today I had an exam on ponters in C, and there was some questions about double pointers where the following syntax was used

```
*pointer = &variable;
```

I don't know if I have done correctly, but can someone explain where will pointer point to and how will the value in variable change? At first I thought it will cause sntax error, but there was no such answer in a test. Thanks in advance

Comment: was it also declared in the same line?

Comment: @dpp that would make it a simple pointer instead of two levels of indirection. Makes more sense for beginners.

Comment: No, not on the same line. It was used at least three times to double pointers. Now I understood what it meant from the answers below, and my theory on test was correct

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev I think it's time to add that info to your question :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm quiet noob in this community :DDDD

Answer (score 1):

```
// two int variables.
int var1;
int var2;

// int pointer pointing to var1
int *ptr = &var1;

// pointer to int pointer..pointing to ptr
int **ptr_to_ptr = &ptr;

// now lets make the pointer pointed to by ptr_to_ptr 
// point to var2
*ptr_to_ptr = &var2;

// or alternatively you can do:
// ptr = &var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pointer is initialized this way:

```
int *pointer;
int variable = 10;

pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
*pointer = &variable;
```

`*pointer = &variable` means the address of variable is set as value of the pointee. Since `*pointer` is dereferencing so you are basically storing a value not setting a reference.

Comment: So then if, for example, address of variable is something like (0x100), then this value will be stored, and pointer will point to it. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: That is if pointer is initialized properly prior to the assignment.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong, I assume that pointer is not a pointer-to-a-pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how you could use it:

```
int foo = 123;
int **bar = malloc(sizeof(int *));
*bar = &foo;
```

Now `bar` is a pointer to a pointer to foo. Doesn't make much sense though.

Comment: Seems like declaration must be added to the question :)

Comment: Your particular example doesn't make much sense, but there are perfectly sensible reasons to do `*pointer = &variable` in general.

Comment: Yes, all of them were questions on double pointers. Now it makes some sense to me

Answer (score 0):

`pointer` is a pointer to a pointer.
Eg,

```
    int var1=42;
    int* intptr;
    int** ptr2intPtr;
    ptr2intptr = &intptr;
//Syntax in question.
    *ptr2intptr = &var1; 
//Just like *intptr is same as var1, *ptr2intptr is same as intptr
//so the above line will be equivalent to intptr = &var1
    //All the three are the same
    printf("%d",**ptr2intptr);
    printf("%d",*intptr);
    printf("%d",var1);
```